# Springboot - @ConfigurationProperties not populating the class fields

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, spring-properties

I know similar questions have been asked many times with different variations. I have tried to learn from them and from the available tutorials and try to get it working but I think I am missing something that I am not able to figure out.

I want to load a configuration from the external yaml file `admin-config.yml`, and not the default `application.yml` in my case.

This is what I have done so far.

1. Annotated the Application file with `@EnableConfigurationProperties`

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class MyServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyServer.class, args);
    }
}
```

2. The `AdminConfig` component class:

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:admin-config.yml")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "admin-config")
public class AdminConfig {

    private List<PrimeModerator> primeModerators;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println(primeModerators);    // this is null
    }

    public void setPrimeModerators(List<PrimeModerator> primeModerators) {
        this.primeModerators = primeModerators;
    }

    public List<PrimeModerator> getPrimeModerators() {
        return primeModerators;
    }
}
```

3. The `PrimeModerator` class

```
@Data
public class PrimeModerator implements Serializable {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private List<String> roles;
    private String details;
    private Date created;
}
```

4. The `admin-config.yml`.

```
admin-config:
  primeModerators:
    - !!com.mydomain.model.PrimeModerator
      id: 1
      name: Pawan
      roles: [super-admin]

    - !!com.mydomain.model.PrimeModerator
      id: 2
      name: Prashant
      roles: [admin, moderator]
```

I have created a unit test case which always fails (which should not).

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class AdminConfigTest {

    @Autowired
    private AdminConfig adminConfig;

    @Test
    public void testAdminConfig() {
        assertNotNull(adminConfig.getPrimeModerators());    // this fails
    }
}
```

I am not sure what I am missing here. Using springboot version `2.2.1.RELEASE` with jdk8.

Thanks for your answers in advance!

Answer (score 0):

from this documentation :
[Baeldung - Spring](http://The%20Hibernate%20Validation%20framework%20uses%20standard%20Java%20bean%20getters%20and%20setters,%20so%20it%27s%20important%20that%20we%20declare%20getters%20and%20setters%20for%20each%20of%20the%20properties.)

It says :
"**The Hibernate Validation framework uses standard Java bean getters and setters, so it's important that we declare getters and setters for each of the properties.**"

Could you please test by adding getters/settest in PrimeModerator ?
Did you try with a single simple String value before you nested array ?
Good luck...

[A github sample on Baeldung in the bottom of page](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot)

Comment: The @Data annotation of Lombok automatically generates getters and setters.

Comment: Yes. I have added @Data annotation from Lombok which should do the work.

Comment: Sorry, without the package I forgot that it was an annotation from Lombok. Is you YML file under src/test/resources ?

Comment: Yes @IssamElHachimi

Comment: What happens if you remove the "!!" line inside your YML ? I think you could start from a working sample and complexify your data structure next... :/